# Search on overridden fields in different collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, collections

I have two collections, global and local. Global contains global data, and local contains overridden data.

A document in global looks like:

```
{
    "sku" : "MAYBE0000001",

    "color" : "BLUE",
    "gender" : "F",
    "variant" : null,
    "price" : "1000"
})
```

A document in local looks like

```
{
    "sku" : "MAYBE0000001",
    "price" : "1500"
}
```

I want to search:

1. For price range from 1300 to 1800 search should give me MAYBE0000001 product, since it's overridden.
2. For price range from 700 to 1300 search should give me 0 results.
3. For search on gender "F", I should get sku MAYBE0000001, since it's not overridden.

How can I run a query after merging price. In future, there might be colour overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with the help of `$lookup`

> 1. For price range from 1300 to 1800 search should give me MAYBE0000001 product, since it's overridden.
> 2. For price range from 700 to 1300 searches should give me 0 results.

I started the query in the local collection. And wrote a range query.

> 3. or search on gender "F", I should get sku MAYBE0000001, since it's not overridden.

For this, I applied the `$match` after lookup.

Here I write the query for same:

```
db.local.aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
      "price":{
        $gt:"1300",
        $lte:"1800"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup:{
      from:"global",
      let:{
        "sku":"$sku"
      },
      pipeline:[
        {
          $match:{
            $expr:{
              $eq:[
                "$sku",
                "$$sku"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as:"lookups"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind:"$lookups"
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "sku":1,
      "price":1,
      "gender":"$lookups.gender",
      "color":"$lookups.color",
      "variant":"$lookups.variant"
    }
  },
  {
    $match:{
      "gender":"F"
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

**Output**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea6f19ac3798d09bdd1c516"),
        "sku" : "MAYBE0000001",
        "price" : "1500",
        "gender" : "F",
        "color" : "BLUE",
        "variant" : null
}
```

For more about `$lookup` refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks. It answers the question. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: Hi Vijay, Can you please let me know how to add the exists case of local on global: 
```//5. if we want to search on global
    $match:{
      "local.gender":{"exists":false},
      "gender":"F"
    }
  }```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case in detail?

Comment: Well for that you have to start aggregation on the global collection and do the lookup on local collection. And then instead of applying a match on the `price`, you should apply it to `gender`.